# Disable the possibility to upload files for user

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm building a service for users where I must have private files.

Actually, with Cloud Code, I can control the download flux, through a function. But, how I can prevent a hacker to use the javascript console and upload his files ? He will get a link, which he can share with anyone without restriction and at my charges.

```
const file = Parse.File('hackerFile', hackerFileArray);
file.save().then(() => console.log(file.url)) // Now, he have a free file hosting.
```

Is there a way to completely remove this feature for everyone, except the master key ?

Example of hosting a file on http://todolist.parseapp.com/

Open the console in your browser then

```
var script = document.createElement('script');

script.src = '//www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.6.14.min.js'; // Because of their version.

document.head.appendChild(script);

Parse.initialize("0Oq3tTp9JMvd72LOrGN25PiEq9XgVHCxo57MQbpT", "vUFy2o7nFx3eeKVlZneYMPI2MBoxT5LhWNoIWPja"); // Found in their sources

var reader = new FileReader();

var input = document.createElement('input');

input.type = 'file';

document.body.appendChild(input);

// Then choose a file from the browser. I choosen a picture.

reader.onloadend = function() {
  var file = new Parse.File('hackFile', {base64: reader.result});

  file.save().then(function() {
    console.log(file.url());
  })
};
reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
```

Then you have a link. I got http://files.parsetfss.com/ae2ddbce-9cc0-4e1a-a16d-52ec5fdb7570/tfss-8fccfba0-ccf7-41cd-8f42-75f0a3478262-hackFile

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Have you asked at parse.com's support on how you can control the uploads? It's the server job to validate uploads.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this, but think it could work:

1) Add a beforeSave function on whatever class you're looking to prevent this behavior on.

2) In the beforeSave, check request.object.dirtyKeys() and iterate through each of those keys on the newly created object.

3) If the value associated with one of those dirtyKeys is a file, don't allow the file to save: `response.error`

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
  var dirtyKeys = request.object.dirtyKeys();
  for (var i = 0; i < dirtyKeys.length; ++i) {
    var dirtyKey = dirtyKeys[i];
    if (isUnwantedFile(request.object, dirtyKey)) {
      response.error("User is not allowed to store files");
      return;
    }
  }
  response.success();
});

//note this function is untested -- I'm not sure what type a user-created file would be, 
//but basically if you can figure that out, substitute it in here
function isUnwantedFile(obj, key){
    return typeof obj[dirtyKey] === Parse.File
}
```